# Force screen readers to interrupt

Tags: javascript, accessibility, screen-readers

I work for a company developing WebGL-based learning content, and we're looking to add more accessibility features to our programs. To that end, I've been trying to find a way to enable screen readers to work, but I'm running into an issue where it can fall behind (say, if hovering over several interactive things in quick succession).

I've put together this demo to illustrate the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/dzqek8os/

When you hover over the coloured squares on the left of the output, it updates a div tagged with `aria-live="assertive"` with the name of the colour, and also outputs when you click on one of the squares. However, when you scrub your mouse quickly over the squares, even though the div is updated immediately, the screen reader (tested with NVDA in my case) doesn't interrupt itself with the update. It does interrupt itself when you click on one of the squares though.

On the right is the behaviour I'm trying to replicate. If you hover over the words (simple p tags in another div), the screen reader does interrupt itself when you hover over a new element.

Other things I've tried:

- appending a new div as a child of an assertive div
- same as above but clearing the parent div before appending the new child
- having 5 separate divs (all with `aria-live="assertive"`) and cycling through which one updates with each hover

Is there a way to replicate the behaviour on the right with JS?

Answer (score 1):

You have no reliable way to tell the screen reader to speak a given message immediately, interrupting whatever currently bein spoken.

Basically, polite means enqueue the message and speak it after all previous messages have been fully spoken.

Assertive means speak the message as soon as possible, but isn't explicitely said in the specs if that "as soon as possible" means interrupt immediately, still finish the current message, still play the entire audio buffer of a few seconds, or anything else.

All screen readers have a slightly different interpretation of that "as soon as possible" due to their implementation and/or point of view of implementors, and immediate interruption may not always be desirable anyway.

Generally, speech is interrupted immediately upon user interaction, i.e. key press, mouse click, etc. because it's very important to immediately give a result to the user. Otherwise the user can think that the app lags.
IN this case, immediate interuption is desirable, just logic, well understood, and that's why it works as you expect, including when moving the mouse over paragraphs.
However, when there is no user interaction, messages should generally never be interrupted so abruptly.

Your foundamental problem is that your canvas presenting a 3D scene is a single element, from the point of view of the browser and screen reader. It isn't aware that there are different sub-elements inside it.
While it's normal to immediately announce when you move over a new element, it isn't normal to interrupt if you stay inside the same element.

Would it be possible to split your 3D scene into different distinct HTML elements? OR is there an API or something to let the browser and screen reader now that your canvas shows different sub-elements? I know for example that, for SVG, you can define individual focusable parts.
This would be the kind of solution you should try.
Doing something like this and additionally making each distinct element of the scene focusable could also be extremely beneficial to keyboard only users, otherwise they are probably unable to use your app.

Comment: Unfortunately, splitting the canvas up isn't really viable. This is "game-like" virtual environment content built in Unity, so we don't have the low level access needed to do something like that, and there would be a host of other problems it would bring.
Your reply has given me some other ideas on hacky workarounds though.

Comment: If your game is built with unity, it probably means that you can make a desktop and/or a mobile app. There you have access to better screen reader / accessibility API than on the web. You may advice screen reader users to download the native app instead of opening it on the web, if the accessibility is better. I would also be curious to know what your workaround is about?

Comment: Unfortunately, a standalone version isn't really viable (we package our content as a SCORM package for LMS's, which pretty much requires it to be web based).
My workaround idea was creating a new element with a transparent image and alt text, and "sweeping" it over the cursor, but the results were.....inconsistent.